# Phalcon Routing Не отрабатывает

Tags: php, phalcon

Помогите с настройками роутинг, есть следующий шаблон запросов с frontend: `/books/([0-9]+)/book-authors/([0-9]+)/images`

Есть контроллер располагается в namespace: `Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors\ImagesController`

В контроллере есть метод indexAction.

В routing.php указываю следующее:

```php
$router = new Router(false);

$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
$router->setDefaultNamespace('Shop\Controllers');
$router->setDefaultController('index');
$router->setDefaultAction('index');

$router->addGet('/books/([0-9]+)/book-authors/([0-9]+)/images', [
    'namespace' => 'Shop\Controllers\Books\BookAuthors',
    'bookId' => 1,
    'authorId' => 2,
    'controller' => 'images',
    'action' => 'index',
]);
return $router;
```

На выходе, получаем, что редикрет всегда идет на default controller.
Подскажите как исправить...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в добавленном роуте /:controller/:action/:params, который отрабатывал раньше всех.
Для решения можно роутингу /:controller/:action/:params указать позицию первый (FIRST) - так как в исходном коде phalcone идет обработка с конца в начало.